# Object Oriented Hangman in Python Version 2.0

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, hangman

I am looking for as much criticism as possible. Specifically I am trying to institute BEST PRACTICES for OOP and game design. Enjoy!

[Github hangman repository](https://github.com/Gershwinfire/hangmanV2)

Each Class is in a separate file and imported.

**BASIC LETTERS CLASS**

```
from enum import Enum



class Letters(Enum):
    a = ('', 'A')
    b = ('', 'B')
    c = ('', 'C')
    d = ('', 'D')
    e = ('', 'E')
    f = ('', 'F')
    g = ('', 'G')
    h = ('', 'H')
    i = ('', 'I')
    j = ('', 'J')
    k = ('', 'K')
    l = ('', 'L')
    m = ('', 'M')
    n = ('', 'N')
    o = ('', 'O')
    p = ('', 'P')
    q = ('', 'Q')
    r = ('', 'R')
    s = ('', 'S')
    t = ('', 'T')
    u = ('', 'U')
    v = ('', 'V')
    w = ('', 'W')
    x = ('', 'X')
    y = ('', 'Y')
    z = ('', 'Z')


    @property
    def unused(self):
        return self.value[1]

    @property
    def dead(self):
        return self.value[0]
```

**GAME LETTERS CLASS**

```
from Letters import Letters

class GameLetters():

    def __init__(self):
        pass       

    def populate_board_letters(self, guessed_letters):

        for letter in Letters:
            if letter.unused.lower() in guessed_letters:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.dead)
            else:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.unused)

        return self.board_letters
```

**UI Class**

```
from GameLetters import GameLetters
import random

class UI(GameLetters):

    def __init__(self):
        self.game_word = self.initialize_game_word()
        self.current_letter = ''
        self.board_letters = []
        self.guessed_letters = []
        self.wrong_guesses = 0
        self.hangman_drawings = [(" _____\n|     |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n__"),(" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|\n|\n|\n__"),(" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|     |\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\n|\n|\n__"),(" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|\n|\n__"),(" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    /\n|\n__"),(" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    / \\\n|\n__")]      
    def get_hangman_drawing(self, failed_attempts):
        
        return self.hangman_drawings[failed_attempts]

    def initialize_game_word(self):

        game_words = []

        with open('words.txt') as file:

            for line in file:
                game_words.append(line.rstrip('\r\n'))

            word = random.choice(game_words)
            return word

    def display_game_word(self):
        

        display_word = ''

        for letter in self.game_word:
            if str(letter) in self.guessed_letters:
                display_word += f"{letter} "
            elif str(letter).upper() in self.board_letters:
                display_word += "_ "
            else:
                print("ERROR: That letter isnt found")
        return display_word
    

    def guess_letter(self):

        while True:
            letter = input("GUESS: ")

            if len(letter) == 1:
                break
            print("Please Only Choose One Letter at a Time")
        letter = letter.strip().lower()
        self.guessed_letters.append(letter)
        self.current_letter = (letter)
        

    def compare_letter(self):
        
        if self.current_letter in self.game_word:
            print("This Letter was found")
            if "_" in self.display_game_word():
                return True
            else:
                print("You Won")
                return False
 
        else:
            print("This letter was most definitely not in the word")
            self.wrong_guesses += 1
            return True
            
    def display_game_state(self):
        self.board_letters.clear()
        self.board_letters = self.populate_board_letters(self.guessed_letters)
        print(f"\n\n\n{self.get_hangman_drawing(self.wrong_guesses)}\n{self.populate_board_letters(self.guessed_letters)}\n{self.display_game_word()}")
```

**Game LOGIC**

```
from UI import UI


class Game:
    def run(self):
        self.game = UI()

        keep_playing = True
        while keep_playing:

            self.game.display_game_state()
            self.game.guess_letter()
            keep_playing = self.game.compare_letter()
            if self.game.wrong_guesses >= len(self.game.hangman_drawings):
                print("Your man has Hanged. Please Try again!")
                break
```

**Execute File**

````
from Game import Game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The entry point ("execute file") as well as the main game loop both look OK. Your `Letters` class doesn't make any sense to me. That's, by the way, also not how enums usually are used. And I don't understand why you have `GameLetters`; you're basically only using it to store a method in a different place.

The overall structure of `UI` is pretty clear. But to call it UI is maybe a bit misleading, since it basically is the entire game.

There's a bunch of smaller improvements you can do here and there. For reading in the list of possible words, you could just do something like

```
def initialize_game_word(self) -> str:
    with open('words.txt') as file:
        game_words = file.readlines()
        return random.choice(game_words)
```

In `UI.display_game_word()` you don't have to convert to `str` since the letters already are strings, and you don't have to use `str.strip()` in `UI.guess_letter()` since you've already asserted that the letter is a single character. But you probably want to make sure that the letter is validated to be a character between a and z - if someone entered a space you would be trying to add an empty string as a guess (since you've stripped the space).

Comment: Super disappointed in not realizing I didnt need to convert to a string, because it is already a string and not an object. Also, I havent really used ENUMS and I am trying to get comfortable with how they can be used. Do you have any suggestions for projects that may implement ENUMS in a manner more standard?

Comment: I don't know how useful it would be to point at a specific project and its usage - I'd suggest that you look into a tutorial or two where they use enums instead.

Answer (score 1):

A note on object oriented programs like this. Usually, defining a class with two methods, one of which being `__init__`, means that whatever function is in the class could probably just be standalone.

For instance, `Game` is not tracking any sort of state. It seems to be a class just for its own sake. If we remove the class:

```py
def game():
    ui = UI()

    keep_playing = True

    while keep_playing:

        ui.display_game_state()
        ui.guess_letter()
        keep_playing = ui.compare_letter()
        if ui.wrong_guesses >= len(ui.hangman_drawings):
            print("Your man has Hanged. Please Try again!")
            break
```

There is zero loss in functionality.

Another example is in `GameLetters`:

```py
from Letters import Letters

class GameLetters():

    def __init__(self):
        pass       

    def populate_board_letters(self, guessed_letters):

        for letter in Letters:
            if letter.unused.lower() in guessed_letters:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.dead)
            else:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.unused)

        return self.board_letters
```

Again, the `__init__` doesn't need to be there, since you `pass`. Reading the functions with that lacking `__init__` means that you *have* to know that this class is to be inherited for `self.board_letters` to make sense. This sends a signal to me that really `populate_board_letters` should be in the `UI` class:

```py
# drop the inheritance
class UI:

    ~snip~
    def populate_board_letters(self, guessed_letters):

        for letter in Letters:
            if letter.unused.lower() in guessed_letters:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.dead)
            else:
                self.board_letters.append(letter.unused)

        return self.board_letters
```

Now the attributes are easy to trace and don't "magically" appear in the instance.

### Hangman Drawings

This attribute is invariant and could probably just be a class variable:

```py
class UI:
    hangman_drawings = [
        (" _____\n|     |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|     |\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    /\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    / \\\n|\n__")
    ]
```

I've also broken up each drawing into its own line for easier reading, which declutters the program a bit.

### Initialized Word

This doesn't belong in the UI class. At the very least, it should be a `@staticmethod` since it doesn't use `self`:

```py
class UI:
    ~snip~

    @staticmethod
    def initialize_game_word():

        with open('words.txt') as file:
            # just collect the lines into a list
            words = file.readlines()
      
        # choose the word and strip off whitespace
        word = random.choice(words).strip()
        return word
```

One other thing I might add is the capability to  pass in a different file:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def initialize_game_word(file='words.txt'):

        with open(file) as fh:
            # just collect the lines into a list
            words = fh.readlines()
      
        # choose the word, strip off whitespace, and set to uppercase
        word = random.choice(words).strip().upper()
        return word
```

### Checking guessed letters

There are a few things going on with checking guessed letter, tracking the last guessed letter, and printing the letters that match the game word. To rework this, I'd track `display_word` in a `list` with a spot that represents a letter in the game word:

```py
class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        ~snip~
        self.display_word = ['_' for _ in self.game_word]
```

The `guess_letter` function can then be modified accordingly:

```py
class UI:
    ~snip~

    def guess_letter(self):
        while True:
            letter = input("Guess a letter: ").strip().upper()
            if len(letter) != 1:
                print("One guess at a time, please")
            elif letter in self.guessed_letters:
                print("You've already guessed that letter!")
                print(f"Try one not in {self.guessed_letters}")
            else:
                break

        self.guessed_letters.add(letter)

        if letter not in self.game_word:
            print("That letter is not in the word")
            self.wrong_guesses += 1
            return
        
        print("That letter was found! Good guess!")

        for i, char in enumerate(self.game_word):
            if letter == char:
                self.display_word[i] = letter


    # and to refactor the display function
    def display_game_word(self):
        # much easier
        print(self.display_word)
```

Note how this rids us of the need to have a `compare_letter` function, which really is a shorthand of `letter in game_word` at its core. I've also forced `letter` to be uppercase, since that's how your display letters are formatted.

Since `display_game_word` doesn't do much at this point, we can get rid of that function entirely.

### Showing used letters

Because the only use for `Letters` is to iterate over it and pick either `unused` or `dead`, I'd say an `Enum` is not the right choice for a data structure. I'd lean towards a `list` here. A trick to build it quickly is that there is a constant distance between your uppercase and blocked letters:

```py
ord('') - ord('A')
127215
```

We can use this to really easily build this list:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppercase

dist = ord('') - ord('A')

LETTERS = [(letter, chr(ord(letter) + dist)) for letter in uppercase]

LETTERS[25]
('Z', '')
```

And now, to use your function:

```py
class UI:
    ~snip~
    def populate_board_letters(self, guessed_letters):

        for letter, dead in LETTERS:
            if letter in guessed_letters:
                self.board_letters.append(dead)
            else:
                self.board_letters.append(letter)

        return self.board_letters
```

Looking closer, though, I don't really love that `self.board_letters` gets `clear`ed. Why not just rebuild it when you call it? Set it as a `@property`:

```py
class UI:
    ~snip~
    @property
    def board_letters(self):
        return [
            dead if letter in self.guessed_letters else letter 
            for letter, dead in LETTERS
        ]
```

Now, this highlights that `display_game_state` would be most convenient to just `print(UI)`. So let's use the `__str__` method:

```py
class UI:
    ~snip~

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"\n\n\n{self.hangman_drawings[self.wrong_guesses]}"
            f"\n{self.board_letters}"
            f"\n{self.display_word}"
        )

# use like this
ui = UI()
print(ui)
```

Notice that now we are directly indexing `hangman_drawings`, referencing `board_letters`, and also referencing `display_word`. We don't need to hide these behind other functions anymore.

### Combining Changes

Now, since we've cut down on how many classes are in this program, I think almost all of it, if not all of it, can effectively be in one file. Here's what we have:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppercase
import random


dist = ord('') - ord('A')

LETTERS = [(letter, chr(ord(letter) + dist)) for letter in uppercase]


class UI:
    hangman_drawings = [
        (" _____\n|     |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|     |\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    /\n|\n__"),
        (" _____\n|     |\n|     O\n|    /|\\\n|    / \\\n|\n__")
    ]

    def __init__(self, words_file='words.txt'):
        self.game_word = self.initialize_game_word(words_file)
        self.display_word = ['_' for _ in self.game_word]
        self.guessed_letters = set()
        self.wrong_guesses = 0


    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"\n\n\n{self.hangman_drawings[self.wrong_guesses]}"
            f"\n{self.board_letters}"
            f"\n{self.display_word}"
        )


    @property
    def board_letters(self):
        return [
            dead if letter in self.guessed_letters else letter 
            for letter, dead in LETTERS
        ]


    @staticmethod
    def initialize_game_word(file='words.txt'):
        with open(file) as fh:
            # just collect the lines into a list
            words = fh.readlines()

        # choose the word, strip off whitespace, and set to uppercase
        word = random.choice(words).strip().upper()
        return word


    def guess_letter(self):
        while True:
            letter = input("Guess a letter: ").strip().upper()
            if len(letter) != 1:
                print("One guess at a time, please")
            elif letter in self.guessed_letters:
                print("You've already guessed that letter!")
                print(f"Try one not in {self.guessed_letters}")
            else:
                break

        self.guessed_letters.add(letter)

        if letter not in self.game_word:
            print("That letter is not in the word")
            self.wrong_guesses += 1
            return
        
        print("That letter was found! Good guess!")

        for i, char in enumerate(self.game_word):
            if letter == char:
                self.display_word[i] = letter


def game():
    ui = UI()

    while True:
        print(ui)
        ui.guess_letter()
        if ui.wrong_guesses >= len(ui.hangman_drawings):
            print("Your man has Hanged. Please Try again!")
            break
        elif ui.display_word == list(ui.game_word):
            print("You won!")
            break
```

### A few last minute tweaks

I'd rename the `game` function to `main`, the `UI` class should be called `Game`. I'd also add in a `lost` function to check if the player has hit the max number of guesses and a `won` function to see if the player guessed the word:

```py
class Game:
    ~snip~
    def lost(self):
        return self.wrong_guesses >= len(self.hangman_drawings)

    def won(self):
        # all letters are filled in properly
        return self.display_word == list(self.game_word)


def main():
    game = Game()

    while not (game.won() or game.lost()):
        # print the game board directly
        print(game)
        game.guess_letter()

    if game.won():
        print("You guessed the word!")
    else:
        print("Your man was hanged! Better luck next time!")
```